# d3.js: Partition layout not propagating to leaves

Tags: d3.js

I'm trying to convert an array of JSON objects (called `dataset`) that looks like this:
[image]

...into, first, a rolled-up version (with music genre as `key`), followed by `d3.layout.partition()`. I'm having trouble with the second step. To `rollup` the data, I use the following code

```
            //Organizing data by genre/tag
            dataset = d3.nest()
                .key(function(d) { return d.tag; })
                .sortValues(function(a, b) { return parseFloat(b.playcount) - parseFloat(a.playcount); })
                .entries(dataset);
```

This works fine, as you can see below:
[image]

Next, I try to use `d3.layout.partition()` to get `depth`, `x`, `y`, etc. propagating to the root node (the `dataset` array itself) and into all the leaves (each `tag`/genre object and its sub-leaves of artists). Here's the code I use:

```
            var partition = d3.layout.partition()
                .sort(null)
                .size([2*Math.PI, radius*radius])
                .value(function(d) { 
                    return 1; 
                });
```

But when I test this with `console.log(partition(dataset))`, I get this:

[image]

As you can see, the `partition` stuff only propagates to the highest level of the data: I get a `depth` of 0 and the `x`, `y` values, etc, but I don't see any of that `depth`, `x`, `y`, etc. in any of my musical genres or artist leaves.

The ultimate goal is to make a [sunburst visualization](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063423) where the inner ring is the genres, and the outer ring is the artists. I can make the visualization with only one ring (for genres), bypassing `partition` altogether. But now I'm stuck. Any help is, as always, appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[d3.layout.partition](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Partition-Layout) follows the hierarchy by looking for `children` attribute:

> Creates a new partition layout with the default settings: the default sort order is by descending value; the default value accessor assumes each input data is an object with a numeric value attribute; **the default children accessor assumes each input data is an object with a children array**; the default size is 1×1.

A little later:

> The children accessor is first invoked for root node in the hierarchy. If the accessor returns null, then the node is assumed to be a leaf node, and the layout traversal terminates. Otherwise, the accessor should return an array of data elements representing the child nodes.

So, with your nested object, partition doesn't see any `children` attribute in your root node and determines it is a leaf.

You can change the [children accessor function](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Partition-Layout#children) to adapt to your structure, or if you want to use the default params you should make your structure like this:

```
{
'name': 'root'
'children': [
  {
    'name': 'rock',
    'children': [
         {'name': 'Pink Floyd', 'playcount': 319, [otherstuff]},
         {'name': 'Rock artist 2', 'playcount': 200, [otherstuff]},
    ]
  },
  {
    'name': 'blues',
    'children': [
         {'name': 'Blues artis 1', 'playcount': 25, [otherstuff]},
    ]
  }
]
}
```

Comment: Thanks, LeartS. I've made some progress, when I make my children accessor function look like this: `function(d) { return d; }`. Unfortunately, this manages to get the `genres` at level 1, but it can't find the `artists` (since they're a `d` or `d` I guess). I'm thinking of standardizing the data structure as you mention, with `name` and `children`. Not sure how to do this, but will investigate!